# Is the password for Amazon's Kindle for PC stored on the computer's hard drive?

Tags: one-time-password

When first using Amazon's "Kindle for PC," it asks you for a password.  Subsequent times using "Kindle for PC," it doesn't ask you for your password.  Is that password stored on the computer's hard drive?   And if so, will a hacker be able to get the password if my computer is compromised?

Comment: I don't know it in this case, but normally the application uses the password to generate a random token for further access to your account.